# Hibernate return duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm writing a web application using spring, spring-mvc, hibernate, MySQL, jQuery, bootstrap.

I have an entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAN_HISTORY")
public class PlanHistory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

     @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_year")
    private LearningYear learningYear;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_gruppa")
    private GroupTbl groupTbl;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_kafedra")
    private Kafedra kafedra;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_discipline")
    private Discipline discipline;

    @Column(name = "n_plan")
    private int nPlan;
    @Column(name = "n_consult")
    private int nConsult;

    @Column(name = "z_lesson")
    private int zLesson;
    @Column(name = "z_lab")
    private int zLab;
    @Column(name = "z_practice")
    private int zPractice;
    @Column(name = "z_consult")
    private int zConsult;
    @Column(name = "z_kurswork")
    private int zKursWork;
    @Column(name = "z_kurswork_ing_fah")
    private int zKursWorkIngFah;
    @Column(name = "z_kurswork_fah")
    private int zKursWorkFah;
    @Column(name = "z_controlwork")
    private int zControlWork;
    @Column(name = "z_cce")
    private int zCce;
    @Column(name = "z_exam")
    private int zExam;
    @Column(name = "z_zalik")
    private int zZalik;
    @Column(name = "z_cpa")
    private int zCpa;
    @Column(name = "z_atest")
    private int zAtest;
    @Column(name = "z_ccrdp")
    private int zCcrDp;
    @Column(name = "z_pzdp")
    private int zPzdp;

    @Column(name = "s_lesson")
    private int sLesson;
    @Column(name = "s_lab")
    private int sLab;
    @Column(name = "s_practice")
    private int sPractice;
    @Column(name = "s_consult")
    private int sConsult;
    @Column(name = "s_kurswork")
    private int sKursWork;
    @Column(name = "s_kurswork_ing_fah")
    private int sKursWorkIngFah;
    @Column(name = "s_kurswork_fah")
    private int sKursWorkFah;
    @Column(name = "s_controlwork")
    private int sControlWork;
    @Column(name = "s_cce")
    private int sCce;
    @Column(name = "s_exam")
    private int sExam;
    @Column(name = "s_zalik")
    private int sZalik;
    @Column(name = "s_cpa")
    private int sCpa;
    @Column(name = "s_atest")
    private int sAtest;
    @Column(name = "s_ccrdp")
    private int sCcrDp;
    @Column(name = "s_pzdp")
    private int sPzdp;
   }
```

with a relation to another entity that looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LEARNING_YEAR")
public class LearningYear {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Ім\'я не може бути пустим")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 2000)
    @Max(value = 3000)
    @Column(name = "begin")
    private int beginYear;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 2000)
    @Max(value = 3000)
    @Column(name = "end")
    private int endYear;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "current")
    private int current;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "learningYear")
    private Set<PlanHistory> planHistory;
}
```

Other entities same as LearningYear;

If I try to fetch data like that from planHistory with criteria LearninYear, Kafedra I get this error:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role

If I add the following in Entity `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` I receive duplicates. I solved that problem by `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`, but I receive  overflow exception when I try to fetch data.

What can I do to avoid the problem?

Comment: Are you using any transaction managmet?

Comment: Yes, i use HibernateTransactionManager

Comment: Can you put  your error stack trace

Comment: https://github.com/alexaht/projectSN all source code can see on git

Comment: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1280)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863

Comment: Can you show your query criteria code ?

Comment: Do you use OpenSessionInViewFilter ?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque `public List<PlanHistory> findAllByYearAndFacultetAndKafedra(int learningYear, int kafedra) {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("learningYear.id", learningYear));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("kafedra.id", kafedra));
        return (List<PlanHistory>) criteria.list();
    }`